# Query Parse Relation with Object ID Only

Tags: parse-platform

I want to conduct a Parse query on a class that has a relation column. From what I understand, I can't pass the entire relation object with a cloud function, I can only pass the `objectId` as a string.

So in my iOS app, I pass the `objectId` like this:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customReport", withParameters: ["thing":thing.objectId]){ (response, error) -> Void in
  println(response)
}
```

Then in my Cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customReport", function(request, response) {
  var promises = []

  var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass")

  //Search for thing
  if(request.params.thing != ""){
    query.equalTo('thing',request.params.thing)

    var promise1 = query.find()

    promises.push(promise1) 
  }

  //...

})
```

But this doesn't work because the `equalTo` statement expects a `thing` object, not an `objectId`.

**Is there a way I can query a relation with just the `objectId`?** Or do I have to query for the `thing` object using the `objectId` and *then* do the `equalTo` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you *can* query by `objectId` after all. You just need to create an empty object with the ID first like this:

```
//In my Cloud Code function...    
var ThingObject = Parse.Object.extend("Thing")
var temporaryThing = new ThingObject()

temporaryThing.id = request.params.thing
query.equalTo('thing',temporaryThing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you cannot pass the relation object directly.  What you can do is pass the objectId of the object that you are searching for in the relation column, then query the class where the relation column is equal to the objectId.

Here is an example if you have a relation column called "friends" on the _User class, and you pass the objectId of the _User object in your iOS app:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFriends", function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("friends", userId);
    query.find({
        success: function(friends) {
            response.success(friends);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting. That's not quite what I'm trying to do, though. In the context of your example, I'm trying to do this: *get all users with the friend "Sam"*. I don't have a user ID to narrow it down to a particular user.

Comment: But you would have the objectId of the user "Sam" by passing it in your iOS app right?

Comment: Yes, I would have Sam's `objectId`.

Comment: See my updated answer.  You just need to query where the relation column is equal to the objectId.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use includeKey...

Basically `myQuery.includeKey("columnName")` will get the whole object for that key when it gets the object that has the pointer to it. 2 for 1!

More:

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the id to a pointer and then you can pass that in to query.whereEqualTo. https://parse.com/questions/updating-a-field-without-retrieving-the-object-first

```
var Point = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
var point = new Point();
point.id = "dlkj83d";
```